# Doctrine 2 Add custom field using DQL is possible?

Tags: doctrine

I can't solve this problem. I have a very large code for filters using a QueryBuilder instance

```
$qb = new QueryBuilder();
$qb->select('item)->from->("BundleExample:Item");
$qb->andWhere("item.idProvince = {$idProvinde");

if($price)

$qb->andWhere("price betwenn..");
```

Ok , there is too much lines.

Now i need to add a virtual column (distance) or overwrite a current field value.

```
$qb->select('item, COS(..) as distance')
```

As i understand , i need to create a ResultSetMapping , but i have to re-do all the filtering process and this is very annoying.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use native queries nor RSM, as Doctrine is capable of returning mixed/hybrid result sets: [Pure and Mixed Results](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results).

Comment: But i want that distance be part of  Item object, not in a different array